# How to flatten a clamped array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, flatten

At the minute I find myself stuck trying to flatten a `Uint8ClampedArray`.

The starting array structure is `data = [227, 138, 255…]` and after creating an array from that of the like `enc = [Uint8ClampedArray[900], Uint8ClampedArray[900], Uint8ClampedArray[900]...]` I try to flatten it.

I tried many methods / solutions for that but no one seems to work:

the MDN suggested method

```
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

with concat

```
data = [].concat.apply([], enc);
```

and through a function

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}
```

but no joy so far, it keeps returning the array as it is. Anyone can point me in the right direction and explain why is that?

-EDIT-
Bottom line: I need it to return a regular Array object, like the starting one not typed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `enc` is an `Array` of `Uint8ClampedArray`s, this one-liner statement should work:

```
var flattened = Uint8ClampedArray.from(enc.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []));
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var flattened = Uint8ClampedArray.from(enc.reduce(function(a, b){
  return Array.from(a).concat(Array.from(b));
}, []));
```

---

To answer your actual question as to why `reduce` didn’t work for you:

```
[].concat(Uint8ClampedArray([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

unfortunately doesn’t return `[1, 2, 3, 4]` but `[Uint8ClampedArray[4]]`. `concat` doesn’t work with Typed Arrays.

Comment: But this converts the typed arrays to a normal array (before converting it back to a typed array). What's the point of using typed arrays, then?

Answer (score 4):

I would calculate the total length first and then use [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set). The advantage of `set` is

> If the source array is a typed array, the two arrays may share the
>   same underlying ArrayBuffer; the browser will intelligently copy the
>   source range of the buffer to the destination range.

```js
function flatten(arrays, TypedArray) {
  var arr = new TypedArray(arrays.reduce((n, a) => n + a.length, 0));
  var i = 0;
  arrays.forEach(a => { arr.set(a,i); i += a.length; });
  return arr;
}
console.log(flatten(
  [new Uint8ClampedArray([1,2,3]), new Uint8ClampedArray([4,5,6])],
  Uint8ClampedArray
));
```

An alternative is using blobs, as [proposed by guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089526/1529630). The proper way would be

```js
function flatten(arrays, TypedArray, callback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    callback(new TypedArray(reader.result));
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(new Blob(arrays));
}
flatten(
  [new Uint8ClampedArray([1,2,3]), new Uint8ClampedArray([4,5,6])],
  Uint8ClampedArray,
  result => console.log(result)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking the MDN, `TypedArray`s doesn't share quite a few normal JS array functions.

You can collect the values from the clamped array, and initialize a new one like this however:

```
var enc = [Uint8ClampedArray.of(1, 2), Uint8ClampedArray.of(4, 8), Uint8ClampedArray.of(16, 32)]

var flattened = Uint8ClampedArray.from(enc.reduce(function(acc, uintc){
  Array.prototype.push.apply(acc, uintc)
  return acc;
}, []));

console.log(flattened); // [object Uint8ClampedArray]
console.log(flattened.join(',')); // "1,2,4,8,16,32"
```

Comment: This seems to work, although it was a bit confusing as to what `a` is supposed to be. If replaced by `enc`, it works.

Comment: I forgot to copy my test array, which was called 'a';

Comment: But this converts the typed arrays to a normal array (before converting it back to a typed array). What's the point of using typed arrays, then?

Comment: It doesn't convert to a normal array, the final flattened array is indeed a `Uint8ClampedArray`. Only the intermediate results, which are values from a typed array are stored in a normal array, which is then reapplied to a typed array.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

firefox, nightly presently returns `[[object Uint8ClampedArray],[object Uint8ClampedArray],[object Uint8ClampedArray]]` at `FileReader()` `result` as pointed out by [@Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089208/how-to-flatten-a-clamped-array/38089526#comment63614970_38089526).

An approach using `spread element`, `rest element`, `for..of`, which returns same results as chromium, chrome utilizing `Blob()`, `FileReader()`; `TextEncoder()`, `TextDecoder()`; `JSON.parse()` approaches

```js
var enc = [new Uint8ClampedArray(900)
            , new Uint8ClampedArray(900)
           , new Uint8ClampedArray(900)];

var res = [];
for (let prop of enc) [...res] = [...res, ...prop];

console.log(res);
```

or, briefer, as suggested by @Oriol

```
var res = [];
var enc = [new Uint8ClampedArray(900), new Uint8ClampedArray(900)]; 
for (let prop of enc) res.push(...prop);
```

---

You can use `Blob()` which concatenates parameters into single `Blob` object, `FileReader()`, `JSON.parse()`

```js
var enc = [new Uint8ClampedArray(900)
            , new Uint8ClampedArray(900)
           , new Uint8ClampedArray(900)];

var blob = new Blob([enc]);

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  console.log(JSON.parse("[" + reader.result + "]"))
}
reader.readAsText(blob);
```

alternatively, using `TextEncoder()`, `TextDecoder()`, `JSON.parse()`

```js
var enc = [new Uint8ClampedArray(900)
            , new Uint8ClampedArray(900)
           , new Uint8ClampedArray(900)];

var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var arr = encoder.encode(enc);
var decoder = new TextDecoder();
var res = JSON.parse("[" + decoder.decode(arr) + "]");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution that I easily understand because I have been working with Blobs before.

Comment: [This doesn't work on Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rQZGc.png). `JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Comment: @Oriol Can you describe "doesn't work"? `JSON.parse: unexpected character` Did not receive error, here, at either approach. Can you create a jsfiddle or plnkr to demonstrate? You could alternatively use `.split(/,/).map(Number)`. What would unexpected character be?

Comment: Not sure if Firefox is doing it right, but `reader.result` is the string `"[[object Uint8ClampedArray],[object Uint8ClampedArray],[object Uint8ClampedArray]]"`. Same for `decoder.decode(arr)`

Comment: @Oriol Interesting. Tried at chromium 50, will try at nightly. What does `TextEncoder`, `TextDecoder` approach return?

Comment: @Oriol Tried at firefox 47 and and nightly 38, received same error. Not certain if this is a firefox bug? Have you tried at chrome, chromium?

Comment: Ah, it's because on Firefox `new Uint8ClampedArray(900) + ''` returns `"[object Uint8ClampedArray]"` instead of `"0,0,0"`. According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%typedarray%.prototype.tostring) I think it should be the latter.

Comment: The update works, but you can just use `var enc = [new Uint8ClampedArray(900), new Uint8ClampedArray(900)];
for (let prop of enc) res.push(...prop);`. BTW, I updated my answer showing the proper way to use blobs with typed arrays.

Comment: @Oriol Had initially wrapped each item at `enc` within another array, which was at OP

Comment: Now that I worked on it I feel like I should accept this answer, more exhaustive and way faster than @Xufox approach.